# How can I compare two objects and add the missed values?

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare two objects by the object value "Datum". In my case I would like to check if the "Datum" value in "mengeGes" is also in the "v" object. If not, then add the values of the "mengeGes" object to the "v" object.

In my example, the object with the "Datum" 2022-02-22 should add from the mengeGes to v:

```js
const mengeGes = [{
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022"
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022"
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-22",
    "Datum_str": "22.02.2022"
  }
]


var v = [{
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  }
]

// The expected result:
v = [{
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-22",
    "Datum_str": "22.02.2022"
  }
]

console.log(v)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I try it with a combination of "forEach" and "find" but I didn't get the correct result :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an array containing the 'missing' objects like so:

```js
var missing = mengeGes.filter(menge => v.filter(vv => vv.Datum === menge.Datum).length === 0);
```

Here we loop over `mengeGes` and filter it by checking if there is an object in `v` where `Datum` maches

---

Then, we can combine that array with the existing `v`:

```js
var combine = [ ...v, ...missing ];
```

```js
const mengeGes = [{
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022"
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022"
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-22",
    "Datum_str": "22.02.2022"
  }
]

var v = [{
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  }
];

var missing = mengeGes.filter(menge => v.filter(vv => vv.Datum === menge.Datum).length === 0);
var combine = [ ...v, ...missing ];
console.log(combine);
```

---

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-20",
    "Datum_str": "20.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-21",
    "Datum_str": "21.02.2022",
    "xx": 4
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2022-02-22",
    "Datum_str": "22.02.2022"
  }
]
```